# Should I use _id for my resources in a mongodb-restful service

Tags: mongodb, rest

I'm developing a restful service. According to RFC 7231, it's good practice to return a location url when using POST to create a resource.

Since I'm using mongodb, I already have an native id created for my resource (BSON _id), should I use this autocreated complex string as id in my resource location url? Or i'm better creating my own simpler id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo's ObjectId is not that complicated, I see no reason not to use it. One advantage of using the automatically generated _id is that this field is always indexed. Another is that Mongo takes care to generate unique ids in all scenarios without you having to implement it. 
If you add your own additional id field you will have two indexes that Mongo has to maintain (since you'll probably want to be able to find documents fast, for example GET requests based on id).

Note that you are not required to use Mongo's auto generated ObjectId, your application can generate unique ids (e.g. running integer), giving you both simpler id and utilization of the built in _id index.